# How to use DepthCorrelatedCoordinateMapper on the Hololens

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx, hololens, c++-winrt

I want to map pixels on the Hololens' color camera to 3d world coordinates. To do that I use the [`DepthCorrelatedCoordinateMapper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.core.depthcorrelatedcoordinatemapper). The Codebase is mainly C++/WinRT, with some parts in C++/CX. I use [a converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx) to get normal references from CX references. I can't collect the needed arguments to construct the mapper because both camera intrinsics and coordinate system are sometimes null.

I oriented myself based on [a example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStreamCorrelation) from Microsoft, specifically this section: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStreamCorrelation/cpp/FrameRenderer.cpp#L127

However, when I try to get the parameters like so:

```
auto video_frame_cx = m_videoFrameProcessor->GetLatestFrame();
auto color_frame_reference = from_cx<MediaFrameReference (video_frame_cx);
CameraIntrinsics camera_intrinsics = color_frame_reference.VideoMediaFrame().CameraIntrinsics();
```

`camera_intrinsics` is null. Polling for a non-null value produces a value for the intrinsics but using the same technique for the coordinate system does not work.

I don't understand where the problem is. It could be a bug in the API. Maybe it is a timing problem? Or the conversion from CX fails/results in weird behaviour?

Comment: It's unclear, why you are calling `from_cx` in the code above. You already have a (projected) C++/WinRT type. Would probably help if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback IInspectable. `m_videoFrameProcessor->GetLatestFrame()` returns a CX reference because I use this VideoFrameProcessor from the samples: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/HolographicFaceTracking/cpp/Content/VideoFrameProcessor.cpp

Comment: @OleSchönburg We are still investing this issue, and I will update here if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, the instruction can be found here: [Media.SharedTexture](https://github.com/carmines/UnityPluginCollection/blob/master/CameraCapture/CameraCapture/Source/Shared/Media.SharedTexture.cpp)

However, in discussing a bit more, we think part of what you are trying to do with the Depth camera is more of a Kinect construct than a HoloLens construct and you will have to do some of that calculations yourselves. 
Part of this will only likely be available in Research Mode (which is not really guaranteed to be supported in future versions of the OS / device). Take a look here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/research-mode

As well as here for a sample that will do what we think you are trying to do:
https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensForCV